# Will it do any damage to the auto transmission if I manually rotate the crankshaft at Parking gear?

Tags: automatic-transmission, timing-belt, crankshaft

Car: VW golf 5 1.6 BSE with 6 speed auto(09G) transmission
Purpose: Replace the timing belt
Reason: Need to turn the crankshaft to match the TDC mark on camshaft pulley

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, this will not cause any damage.

Cars have the engines running while they are in park.

Park is a selection in the ´box that allows the fluid to circulate without providing any drive to the wheels.